# How to clean spilled honey on piece of cloth/mattress?

Tags: cleaning

I have honey spilled on mattress, How could I remove and clean it?
[image]

Comment: I want to say: Use Winnie the Pooh, or maybe Tigger.

Comment: that only works when its spelled "hunny" ...

Answer (score 4):

rub in **a little** neat dishwashing liquid using a sponge all over, then use hot water dabbed on with a towel, to remove both. It will take time to dry out.

Answer (score 1):

I use vinegar and dish washing soap for sticky stains.. dilute the vinegar with an equal part of warm water with the dish soap already in it and use a towel to ***scrub the daylights*** out of the stain.

Alternatively Skin-So-Soft works wonders on sticky things but ***will*** cause dyes/pigments too run and bleed

Answer (score 0):

Always, the best practice when something similar occurs accidentally is to act gently.
The following can also be performed to remove honey stains:

- Outside to inside wiping using a spoon to remove extra honey that you can extract from the affected surface, and don't take it for edible purpose.
- Using a dull knife to scramble up the solidified honey from the affected surface.
- As everyone will suggest washing under clean cold water, this can also be listed, but to be done from the backside so that, water will carry away honey components.
- Trying out stain removers available in your market is also appreciable.
- Treat affected part with hot water. Soak the part and wipe out with the cloth. Repeat the steps.Increasing temperature makes honey dissolve into water.
  (*Please note that certain of them may fade after this treatment. Please check with company instructions, if they can bear the temperature, then only go for this*)
- If nothing works, please resort to dry cleaning or any other chemical treatments.

Comment: cold water will coagulate the honey further, and even if he could get to the backside of the stain, its on a mattress and the mattress is sealed. Water alone, hot or cold will not remove honey, you need **detergent**.

Answer (score 0):

Honey definitely contains sugar.If and when sugar dries on a surface, it remains sticky in a seemingly weird way. Therefore, wipe repeatedly with a wet piece of cloth to dilute the sugary content and leave it to dry.